# Permission Denied on Solaris 10 NFS share, shared trough Windows Server 2008R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, nfs, solaris

We have a NFS share on Windows Server 2008 R2.
NTFS permissions for ANONYMOUS LOGON and Everyone groups are set to Full control.
When mounting this share on our Solaris workstation, it mounts and we can view files in that mount but cannot edit or write to it.

```
mount -f nfs 10.0.0.2:/Folder/ /test
```

permissions are set as:

```
drwxrwxrwx   2 nobody   nobody      4096 Mar  4 08:57 test/
```

when in test direcorie, trying to copy a file gives this error:

```
cp gp.txt gp_1.txt
cp: cannot create gp_1.txt: Permission denied
```

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: How are the Share (not NTFS) permissions configured?

Comment: can you post the output of 'mount' and 'id -a' on the solaris machine also please.